# Android localization (change language) with runtime application using free language translator

Tags: android, localization, language-translation

I am developing my Android application in those languages that support given by Android OS in Android devices. The application will automatically pick device language and localizes with my application. I want to pass the only English text to the online/offline translator and show the localized text on the application UI. I found most of the solutions are managed by using .csv file or string.xml or using .json or API/web services but in normal Android devices 50+ languages support given by Android OS. so these solutions will make me more headachy to all the languages because many devices have different languages and if we trying to handle it as an implementation wise, it makes more difficult for us.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "will not work on all the languages"? Just add country code to end of your resource folder and it should do the trick. Check this page for more info about renaming resource folders: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Comment: I edited the above statement. If we try to add string files for every language it makes 50-100 string files for a single Android application. I think we have to search a better way than this.